# How to save a mp3 file through your browser in a dicretory on your PC?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to webdevelopment, so please keep that in mind when this question seems stupid.

I am trying to bulid a simple webpage to upload mp3 files through a form.
I am just working with local directorys. Not with a server!
For testing I would like to "upload" the mp3 to a local directory on my PC. In other words: I would like to open my page, navigate to a mp3 file on my computer and "upload" (copy) it to another directory on my PC!

Is this even possible?

Comment: Normally web pages don't have access to the file system of the user. ( Can you imagine what kind of damage criminals would be able to do if that were possible? )  But  if you run everything locally, it should be possible. Have a look at the File API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications to learn how to 'upload' a file from your disk to the web page. And then make it available for downloading somehow. Eg. by creating a hyperlink with the file set as the target. My biggest question would be 'why'? Copying files locally only takes one line in cmd

Comment: You could set up a webserver on your local machine which should allow you to test uploading and downloading.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
The purpose of this is just for learning! I want to test if it works and I dont have a server.

Comment: @kurwamonk You can run server software directly on your computer.  That's what you should do.